# How to know which element receives the click()?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a script that goes to an Amazon URL and clicks on the 'Buy Now' button. That's it. I have to use WebdriverIO, javascript, and ChromeDriver. The problem is that I can't get this button to be clicked no matter which selector I use. I am able to manually do it just fine. But in the Code Inspect below, every combination of div/id/name, span/id/close, or input/id/name has resulted in no clicks. I know the script can see that web object because when I do a BuyNow.getText() to console, it prints out 'Buy Now'. And I know the xpath I use is good because I paste it into Inspect/Find and the exact element lights up yellow. Oh and the .click(), even though Visual Studio Code flags as deprecated, works just fine in previous scripts.

When I manually click on a button, is there a way to see what was the exact element that received this click?

```
        let BuyNow = $(<XPATH>)
        BuyNow.click()
```

[Code Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unpn7.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. With the information you provided, this would be a long game of 21 questions. Can you please have a look at the [tour], and provide a [mcve], so that we are able to help you.

Comment: I don't understand how this would be a long game of 21 questions. Look at the Code Inspect picture, which is the short block of code that relates to Amazon Buy Now button. It's the same for every product.  Why is it is that even though I did a correct XPATH of every line, and put it in the declare button code, WebdriverIO was never able to click it? And finally, is there an easy way to determine which line of code is responsible for the button click?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found out what the problem was. It had nothing to do with my XPATH selectors, any one of which to the elements in the Code Inspect picture would have worked (example: let BuyNow = *[id='buy-now-button']). The issue is that in the WDIO config file, I had a custom Chrome Profile being used. Which is fine, the Chrome.exe I was using was pointing to another custom Chrome Profile. I thought these two were the same, but the folders paths were getting messed up. Once I resolved them, and had both the Chrome.Exe and WDIO config pointing to the same customer folder, Chrome started to allow me to select buttons. I think that the WDIO code was looking at one user profile of chrome, and the desktop chrome browser that I was using was another user profile.

Solved. Fun Stuff but not really.